# Access 2010 SQL query select inner join with temporary tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, inner-join

In Access 2013 using VBA I am running an SQL query where a table (CUSTOMERS_TEMP) has a monthly_total which is the sum of sales_price in a temporary table (SALESHIST) taken from a SALESHIST_TEMP table. I'm not sure why this is not working.

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "Update CUST " _
    & "SET CUST.Monthly_Total = SALESHIST.Monthly_Total " _
    & "FROM CUSTOMERS_TEMP AS CUST " _
    & "INNER JOIN (SELECT KEY, SUM(SALES_PRICE) AS MONTHLY_TOTAL FROM SALESHISTORY_TEMP GROUP BY KEY) AS SALESHIST " _
    & "ON CUST.Key = SALESHIST.Key "
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: You are not putting spaces  between the line continuations.  For example when VBA concatenates it sees `= SALESHIST.Monthly_TotalFROM CUSTOMERS_TEMP`  Put spaces before the quotes at the end of each line.

Comment: Ok that's fixed. Now I have a syntax error missing operator in access

Comment: @LambentDelphian Not in this code, I assume? If it is running the SQL that's giving the error, I would first try adding a line before the `RunSql` like: `Debug.Print SQL : Stop`. Run the code, it will stop there. Hit CTRL+G to see the immediate window. copy the SQL from there.  Create a new Access query, go into SQL view, paste the sql statement, and run. Do you get the error there too?   Is it easier to troubleshoot there?

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit to test parts of the query.

Comment: why using temp tables instead of queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [DSum domain aggregate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32) for an updateable query. Also consider saving your query as stored object in database as it is more efficient since Access engine can compile it for best execution plan. Also, avoid *Key* for column name as it is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe).

**SQL**

```sql
UPDATE CUSTOMERS_TEMP CUST 
SET CUST.Monthly_Total = DSum("SALES_PRICE", "SALESHISTORY_TEMP", 
                              "[Key]='" & CUST.[Key] & "'")
```

**VBA**

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "mySavedQuery", dbFailOnError
```

Finally, reconsider saving aggregate data in source tables as you can always query them as needed and avoid the storage resource.

Comment: Where do you get the error: SQL or VBA? What are the types of *Key* fields?

Comment: Key is a short text field which is together four or so letters for a name and then numbers also such as 001, eg test001, the error is in access when I manually test the sql in a query. It says that all the records in the data from the query are type mismatched

Comment: See edit with *Key* in DSum's criteria is now wrapped in quotes since it is a text type.

Comment: DSum in a query is very unefficient. It's OK if you have a few 100 rows only.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez ... Agreed and engine cannot optimize an external function or use indices. I welcome suggestions for running `UPDATE` on aggregated sums in MS Access. But back to my final point to OP of storing aggregate/queryable data in source tables.

Comment: Hi, the SQL still doesn't work. When I run this in the sql query design run part of access it still says only 1 field was not updatable.

Comment: So now this query runs in isolation in the sql query design. When I reference this query in vba after other aspects I get a runtime error 3075 'unknown'

Comment: This query should work. The *conversion error* is due to data types of table design. Make sure CUSTOMERS_TEMP's *Monthly_Total* is the same type as SALESHISTORY_TEMP's *SALES_PRICE* such as text vs number and even integer vs double.

Comment: Replace single quotes in that field with double quotes to escape the outside single quote. This means quite a bit of single quotes 4 and 6 in the `Replace` call inside DLookUp: `Replace(CUST.[Key], '''', '''''')`

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help. Can you delete all prior comments for future readers? Hover over comment and `x` should appear.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, the syntax for `UPDATE`/`JOIN` is different from SQL Server.

It looks like:

```
Update CUSTOMERS_TEMP AS CUST INNER JOIN
       (SELECT KEY, SUM(SALES_PRICE) AS MONTHLY_TOTAL
        FROM SALESHISTORY_TEMP
        GROUP BY KEY
       ) AS SALESHIST
       ON CUST.Key = SALESHIST.Key
    SET CUST.Monthly_Total = SALESHIST.Monthly_Total;
```

You can also write this as:

```
Update CUSTOMERS_TEMP AS CUST
    SET CUST.Monthly_Total = (SELECT SUM(SALES_PRICE) AS MONTHLY_TOTAL
                              FROM SALESHISTORY_TEMP
                              WHERE SALESHISTORY_TEMP.Key = CUST.Key
                             )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SALESHISTORY_TEMP
                  WHERE SALESHISTORY_TEMP.Key = CUST.Key
                 );
```

Comment: I tried this code and removed the error quotation mark and now it says operation must use an updateable query

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried this again and it still didn't work. It still says operation must use an updateable query

Comment: @LambentDelphian try changing the query `Recordset Type` to `Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)`